# useMemo used to track history.location.search is not trigered in test environment

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I have a hook that reads and writes to url. It adds and reads query params.
Here is what it looks like

```
// usage
const [filtersValues, setFiltersValues] = useURLState(mergedInitialValues);

// the hook itself
export const useURLState = (initialState: any) => {
  const history = useHistory();

   const stringifyQuery = (queryAsObject: Record<string, any>) => {
    const { date, ...rest } = queryAsObject;
    
    const queryToStringify = ...rest;
    return queryString.stringify(queryToStringify, ARRAY_FORMAT);
  };

  const parseQueryString = useCallback((queryParams: string) => {
    const parsed = queryString.parse(queryParams, ARRAY_FORMAT);
   
    return parsed;
  }, []);

  const addQueryParamsToUrl = useCallback(
    (newQueryAsObject: Record<string, any>) => {
      const newQuery = stringifyQuery(newQueryAsObject);
      const currentQuery: string = history.location.search.slice(1); // remove leading ? in current location

      // prevent infinite loop
      if (currentQuery !== newQuery) {
        history.push({ search: newQuery });
      }
    },
    [history]
  );

  useMemo(() => {
    const mergedQueryParams = {
      ...initialState,
      ...parseQueryString(history.location.search)
    };

    addQueryParamsToUrl(mergedQueryParams);
  }, [addQueryParamsToUrl, initialState, history.location.search, parseQueryString]);

  const setFiltersState = useCallback(
    value => {
      addQueryParamsToUrl(value);
    },
    [addQueryParamsToUrl]
  );

// NOTE THIS USE MEMO
// it just parses search string and returns values as object for convenience
// used this way so url is the only source of data

  const filtersAsPlainObject = useMemo(() => {
    // query-string will not make single value an array
    // e.g. ?foo=bar will never be parsed as foo = ['bar']
    // therefore need to ensure it with this helper
    const parsed = parseQueryString(history.location.search);
    const result: Record<string, any> = getTypeSafeValues(initialState, parsed);

    return merge(cloneDeep(initialState), withDateFiltersHandled);
  }, [parseQueryString, initialState, history.location.search]);

  return [filtersAsPlainObject, setFiltersState];
}
```

When I test it in browser it works fine and useMemo which returns filtersAsPlainObject always gets the latest values;
However problems come when I try to test it with react-testing-library and jest.

As soon as I try to update any filters in any way, (e.g. clear them all). history.location.search is updated. I can clearly see it in my test.

E.g.
BEFORE CLEANING

```
?grade=gradeK,grade1&location=zoom&type=camp,course
```

AFTER

```
'' // just empty string
```

But what is really odd to me, is that **useMemo** is not fired and new values are not received. So previous values are returned. Any idea what am I doing wrong here?
(It was obvoius to me that when history.location.search changes **useMemo** should be triggered and new values should be returned from hook. But for some reason that doesn't happen)